# traducir este codigo de c++ a c#

Tags: c#

Hola tengo problemas al traducir este código a c# no sé muy bien como usar la función o hacer lo mismo que hago en qt. el código es el siguiente:

```
QFile *archivo;
archivo = new QFile();
archivo->setFileName(QApplication::applicationFilePath());
archivo->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
archivo->seek(archivo->size() - 1024);
trama = archivo->read(1024);
```

codigo:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
{
    if (reader.BaseStream.Length > 1024)
    {
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(-1024, SeekOrigin.End);
    }
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Hay alguna manera posible de hacer lo mismo pero en c#?

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo My Dear?

Comment: se que para leer los bytes de mi fichero hago `byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);` pero no se muy bien como hacer un seek como hago en en c++ porque me parece que la funcion es diferente.

Comment: respuesta rápida: Sí, hay maneras posibles de hacerlo en C#. La pregunta para ti es: ¿Dónde está ese código en C# que has intentado? Si lo tienes, edita tu pregunta y agrégalo, así veremos el esfuerzo de tu parte y con mayor ganas la comunidad te ayuda :D

Comment: puse lo que intente que es basicamente el codigo de la comunidad inglesa.

Comment: con eso saco el final pero ahora se me presento otro problema.